# How can I convert my datetime to a string?

Tags: c#, wpf

```
 private void calendar_SelectedDatesChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        // ... Get reference.
        var calendar = sender as Calendar;

        // ... See if a date is selected.
        if (calendar.SelectedDate.HasValue)
        {

            DateTime date = calendar.SelectedDate.Value;
            this.Title = date.ToShortDateString();
            Stream stream = File.Open(Convert.ToString(date+".txt"), FileMode.Open);
            textbox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            textbox.Text = "";
            stream.Close();

        }


    }
```

I want to create a new text file if the user clicks on the calendar. The name of the text file should be the date the user clicked.

```
Stream stream = File.Open(Convert.ToString(date+".txt"), FileMode.Open);
```

This line produce a System.NotSupportedException

Edit: I think the whole code would help more

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="Terminkalender.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Kalender" Height="350" Width="525" >
<Grid>
    <Calendar  SelectedDatesChanged="calendar_SelectedDatesChanged" Name="calendar" Background="Orange" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="310" Width="178" RenderTransformOrigin="0.528,0.769"/>
    <TextBox Name="textbox" AcceptsReturn="True" Visibility="Hidden" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="149" Background="Aqua" Margin="245,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="248"/>
    <!--SelectedDatesChanges erstellet eine Methode die im Falle eines geklickten Datum ein Ereignis ausführt-->
</Grid>
```

C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.IO; 

namespace Terminkalender
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaktionslogik für MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void calendar_SelectedDatesChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        // ... Get reference.
        var calendar = sender as Calendar;

        // ... See if a date is selected.
        if (calendar.SelectedDate.HasValue)
        {

            // ... Display SelectedDate in Title and change Visibility of textbox
            DateTime date = calendar.SelectedDate.Value;
            this.Title = date.ToShortDateString();
            Stream stream = File.Open(Convert.ToString(date + ".txt"), FileMode.Open);
            textbox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            textbox.Text = "";
            stream.Close();
        }


    }


}
```

}

Comment: `File.Open(date.ToString() + ".txt"), FileMode.Open);`?

Comment: Btw, you need `FileMode.OpenOrCreate`. `Open` will throw `FileNotFoundException` if the file does not exist.

Comment: @ Nikola I will get the same execption.

Comment: @ Grant of course. Just tested some things and forget to correct it for the question - my bad.

Comment: An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in mscorlib.dll. 

Additional information: The path specified format is not supported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use Convert.ToString(args), you can directly convert the date to string.

```
Stream stream = File.Open(date.ToString()+".txt"); FileMode.Open);
```

if you have trouble with the format of the string date, you can refer to this 
[Link](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Stream stream = File.Open(Convert.ToString(date) +".txt", FileMode.Open);
```

Your `".txt"`, which is a string, is inside a function that converts nonstrings to strings.

In order to save as a valid filename, you should format the datetime so it will not produce invalid characters in your filename. (petelids)

Using the `.ToString` extension you can automatically format the `DateTime`.

```
Stream stream = File.Open(date.ToString(MMddyyyy) + ".txt", FileMode.Open);
```

Comment: You'll need to be careful of invalid file name characters - it might be worth adding a format - e.g. `date.ToString("MMddyyyy")`

Comment: I tried this too. Result: - An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in mscorlib.dll. 

Additional information: The path specified format is not supported

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle illegal file name characters so you should pass a format string to the `ToString()` method. For example:

```
Stream stream = File.Open(date.ToString("MMddyyyy HHmm") + ".txt", FileMode.Open);
```

There is more information on the `DateTime.ToString()` method including different format options on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Ok - it works now. I thought dates like 10.09.2014 should be ok for the string path because it worked on the title too. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 0):

You can format the DateTime using something like

```
date.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")
```

This should ensure that the file name does not have any illegal characters coming from the date.